# How to bind data object

Tags: scala

I have a data object:

```
case class Id(val value: String) extends AnyVal {
  def bind[A](f: ((String) => A)): A = {
    f(value)
  }
}
```

I want to bind Id to the first argument of `String.format`:

```
id.bind(template.format)
```

But I get the error `type mismatch: Seq[Any] => String => String`

I believe this is because `template.format` can take a variable amount of arguments.

Is there a way that I can make a nice reusable bind function like this?

Edit: (I do not want to leak the val of Id because I am trying to implement a tell don't ask strategy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a lambda in your call to bind, then everything should be fine:

```
id.bind(s => template.format(s))
```

Alternatively, you could change your bind function to accept `Seq[Any]`:

```
def bind[A](f: ((Seq[Any]) => A)): A = {
  f(Seq(value))
}
```

Or:

```
def bind[A](f: (String*) => A): A = {
    f(value)
}

id.bind(template.format) // Works!!!
```